# is there a way to dynamic include a bean in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have a scheduling process in Spring to run every 5 mins. More interesting upgrade is this make a switch to choose this schedule process or another web service. Sure I can make this work with properties setting and java, but there are a few beans defined in application context that I have to take care of

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <!-- always keep A,B,C,E -->
            <ref bean="triggerA" />
            <ref bean="triggerB" />
            <ref bean="triggerC" />
            <!-- some sort of condition to enable this ref or not -->
            <ref bean="triggerD_I_want_an_option_to_disable_ahhhhhhhhhh" enabled="false"/>
            <ref bean="triggerE" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I know it could be a fantasy to have such a switch for Spring bean collections, but please let me know if there is any way I can simply make a bean turn on / off by properties file, like

```
  <bean enable="${thisBeanEabled}" id="..." class="com.Chrstimas.all.gifts.are.Free"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need let `triggerD_I_want_an_option_to_disable_ahhhhhhhhhh` implments [SmartLifeCycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html), add a boolean field, which autowired with a property, value of this field would be returned by `isAutoStartup()`